# Play 2.5.9 + cucumber, JPA withTransaction deprecated

Tags: scala, jpa, playframework-2.0, cucumber

I am trying to write following database test with cucumber :

```
@Given("^I have N foos$")
public void i_have_N_foos() throws Throwable {
    JPA.withTransaction(() -> {
        fooSize = foo.count();
    });
}
```

`foot.count()` should be in a transaction but`JPA.withTransaction` method is deprecated. How can I use `JPAApi` with my cucumber test?

Comment: I have not worked with Cucumber but, you should be able to `@Inject JPAApi` into your test.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with :

```
public class Foo{

JPAApi jpaApi;

@Given("^I have N foos$")
public void i_have_N_foos() throws Throwable {
jpaAPI= JPA.createFor("fooPersistenceUnit");
jpaApi.withTransaction(() -> {
    fooSize = foo.count();
});
}

}
```